# regex with multiline modifier work on server but not work on xampp localhost

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a regex that work fine on internet and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oL8iA9/1)

I use below PHP codes to test it in localhost

```
<?php
$regex = "/(?:دفتر)(?:.*?)\:(?:.*?|\n)(^(?!.*\@).+)/mu";
preg_match_all($regex,$str, $arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

but when run it on XAMPP localhost it return's empty array , what's wrong with this code and, how can I fix it

Comment: Try a `var_dump($regex); var_dump($str);` too.

Comment: I guess you forgot the `/u` modifier - please show the `$regex` declaration.

Comment: i try both them and is not any different with online regex editor

Comment: Online tester is doing that for you. You must use `/u` in PHP regex if you work with Unicode strings. Oh, and the delimiters. Try `$regex = '/(?:دفتر)(?:.*?):(?:.*?|\n)(^(?!.*@).+)/mu';`

Comment: Are you sure you sourrounded your regex with `/` and added the modifieres? `/(?:دفتر)(?:.*?)\:(?:.*?|\n)(^(?!.*\@).+)/mu` ?

Comment: @stribizhev i try /u /mU /U but no result show

Comment: `/U` is an greediness-swapping modifier. It has nothing to do with `/u`. Do you have the pages saved  with UTF8 encoding? Do you have `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`?

Comment: @stribizhev yes i do save page with UTF8 encoding and add 'ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');' on top

Comment: @stribizhev from  [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?629775-preg_match_all-and-multiline) is probelm because windows line endings ?

Comment: Try `'/(?:دفتر)(?:[^:\n]*):.*\R((?!.*@).+)/mu'` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL8iA9/2)).

Comment: well done ...thanks a lot it's work fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for different variants of newline sequences. In Windows, CR+LF, in Linux, LF, in MacOS, it is CR.

In PCRE, you have a very handy shorthand class `\R` that matches **any newline sequence**.

So, use

```
'/(?:دفتر)(?:[^:\n]*):.*\R((?!.*@).+)/mu'
```

And do not forget the `/u` modifier that will force the regex engine to treat both the pattern and the input string as UTF8 strings.

Note that `/U` modifier is NOT the same as `/u`. `/U` only swaps greediness.

```
/%(.*?)%/U = /%(.*)%/
/%(.*?)%/ = /%(.*)%/U
```

Comment: Note that I optimized your regex a bit. The negated character class `[^:\n]*` will match 0 or more characters other than `:` or linefeed and is much more effecient than `.*?`. Also, `(?:.*?|\n)` makes little sense, alternations involve backtracking and should be avoided if possible - I changed it to `.*\R` which is *linear*. You can further enhance it with possessive quantifier with `.*+@`: `(?:دفتر)(?:[^:\n]*):.*\R((?!.*+@).+)`.